# O que é um offset?

Tags: offset

Boa, estou pesquisando sobre cheats para jogos e me deparei com o termo "offset", pesquisei sobre e nao passei do pensamento, de que offset é um calculo da distancia do endereço até onde vc quer alocar tal váriavel. esse pensamento está certo? caso não, oq é offset?

Answer (score 2):

Acho que depende muito do contexto, porque a palavra em si, só quer dizer `deslocado`, `compensado`, `equilibrado`...

Considerando o contexto que você citou, endereçamento de memória, consideraria o `offset` como o deslocamento do endereço desejado. Logo, acredito que seu pensamento: "é um calculo da distancia do endereço até onde vc quer alocar tal váriavel" está correto.

Comment: É isso mesmo, o deslocamento em relação a uma posição inicial ou posição-raiz.

Answer (score 2):

- O que é um offset?

Offset, como já respondido, é onde está alocado uma informação do processo em relação a uma posição. Em forma escrita é isso, mas para o assunto, prefiro dar exemplos e mostrar imagens:

Para nos basearmos melhor, vamos supor que um jogo(processo) possui a seguinte arquitetura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vamos supor os seguintes offsets:

```
ClientDll = 0x12EA567; //Em relação ao ponto inicial, esse seria o modulo em que vamos trabalhar
Localplayer = 0x4BCD3F; //Em relação ao ClientDll
Vida = 0x100; //Em relação ao Localplayer
```

Como fazer para pegar a vida do jogador local? Simples! Some tudo:

```
VidaDoJogador = ClientDll + Localplayer + Vida;
```

Perceba que o que fizemos, é pegar uma informação que está contida em um processo a partir de um endereço que conseguimos pelos offsets.

**Em código real (C++ & WinAPI):**

```
int VidaDoJogador = 0;
DWORD endereço = ClientDll + Localplayer + Vida;

ReadProcessMemory(processo, (void*)endereço, &VidaDoJogador, sizeof(VidaDoJogador), 0);
```

Onde `processo` é o [`HANDLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx) do processo.

- Por que não trabalhar com offsets?

Offsets são bem dinâmicos e podem mudar sempre que o código fonte do processo muda. Recomendo dar uma lida em Pattern Scanner, em que ao invés de criar variáveis para os offsets e ter que ficar mudando sempre, ele os encontra para você, de acordo com os valores estáticos próximos a ele.